# Query Jenkins for last few builds

Tags: api, jenkins, build

How can query Jenkins using API to know the last few builds that it executed. I don't know the name of build jobs. I just want Jenkins to return the last n builds it executed or the builds executed between 2 timestamps

Comment: Try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54191349/1805453

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to query build results via API , you have to know the **job name** in Jenkins. You have to append your jenkins job **URL** with the this suffix `/api/json` to get the **JSON** data String.

For ex: If your Jenkins server has a job named **A_SLAVE_JOB** , then you have to do a  **HTTP** *GET* in your java rest client at this end point : `http://<YourJenkinsURL>:<PortNumber>/job/A_SLAVE_JOB/api/json`

This shall return a String with all the build history URL (with numbers), Last successful build and last failed build status.

You can traverse the subsequent build of a given job using a **for** loop. All you need is a JSON parser for extracting values from keys in JSON string. You can use `org.json` library in java to do the parsing.  A pseudocode sample goes like this :

```
   import org.json.*;
    class myJenkinsJobParser {
    public static void main(String... args){
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject("YOUR_API_RESPONSE_STRING");
    String pageName = obj.getJSONObject("build").getString("status");

    JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("builds");
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++)
    {
        String url = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("url");
        // just a psuedoCode......
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to summarize. The way you have to request info. Below number 0, 5 it's range of latest 5 builds.

```
curl -g "${SERVER}/job/${JOB}/api/json?pretty=true&tree=builds[number,url,result]{0,5}" \
  --user $USER:$TOKEN
```