# Jenkins API - filter last builds for how are triggered and time

Tags: jenkins, devops, jenkins-api

Hello I need to get every night last builds triggered by timer, check status and if unsuccessful re-trigger.
Couldn't find a way how to filter a build for particular time and by how is triggered

```
curl --insecure --user test:test 'https://jenkins.domain.com/job/leaves/job/tenant/job/develop/
```

Any tips guys?

Answer (score 0):

You could leverage this [groovy script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64509896/598141). Use `job.scheduleBuild2(0)` to trigger a new build.