# Shell Script to gather the total number of Jenkins jobs has run between the particular time period along with succeed and failed build status

Tags: jenkins, curl, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

Is there a way using a shell script or by using Curl command we can get the info like within particular time span the total number of jobs got created, jobs succeded, and the number of jobs got failed in jenkins.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jenkins Plugin to list total number of jobs, total number of build failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73216661/jenkins-plugin-to-list-total-number-of-jobs-total-number-of-build-failure)

Comment: am getting some error, updated the error status in parent thread.