# Jenkins daily report - jobs build history report in email

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

My requirement is to create a Jenkins job that runs everyday EOD, where

1. I declare a list of job names, the job should iterate through each job and print all **successful build history** that happened that day.
2. The printed message should print **current iteration Job name**, then each **Build number, Build status, build completed timestamp, git commit id, commit message, commit author**.

This printed message should be emailed to declared recipients.

Please share chunks of code or references that will be helpful. I am new to Jenkins and groovy. The chunks will be helpful for many as well. Solutions that works with only default plugins will be grateful.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is too abstract and contains multiple questions. I typically don't like answering such questions, but here is a starting point for you. The following script will get you all the Jobs and Builds that Ran during the past 24 Hours.

```
Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(Job.class).each { jobitem ->
      def jobName = jobitem.getFullName()
      def jobInfo = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(jobName)
  
      // Current time in Miliseconds
      def now = new Date().getTime()
      def before24Hours = now - (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
      println("Now: " + now + " Before24H: " + before24Hours)
      
      jobInfo.getBuilds().byTimestamp(before24Hours, now).each { build ->           
        if(build.getResult().toString().equals('SUCCESS')) {
          println("Job : " + jobName + " || BuildNumber: " + build.getNumber() + " || Timestamp: " + build.getTime())
        }
      }
}
```

Remember each Build can have multiple commits, hence multiple users. You can get the commit details with [this](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/workflow-job/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/job/WorkflowRun.html#getChangeSets()) method.

Start building your pipeline with the above and create SO questions for problems you face while doing it. Don't combine multiple questions into the same question.

---

Update:
Full Pipeline to include commit details.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Report') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def jobsToInclude = ['Job1', 'Job2']
                    generateReport(jobsToInclude)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

def generateReport(def jobs) {
      Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(Job.class).each { jobitem ->
          def jobName = jobitem.getFullName()
          if(jobs.contains(jobName)) {
               
              def jobInfo = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(jobName)
              // Current time in Miliseconds
              def now = new Date().getTime()
              def before24Hours = now - (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)

              jobInfo.getBuilds().byTimestamp(before24Hours, now).each { build ->  
                
                if(build.getResult().toString().equals('SUCCESS')) {
                  println("Job : " + jobName + " || BuildNumber: " + build.getNumber() + " || Timestamp: " + build.getTime())
                  // Get the commits
                  build.getChangeSets().each{change -> 
                    change.getItems().each { item ->
                      println("---" + "COMMITID: " + item.getCommitId() +  " || Message: " + item.getMsg() + " || Author: " + item.getAuthorName())
                    }
                  }   
                }
            }  
         }
    }  
}
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing. Ofcourse I also don't like to ask such questions. Just thought of having all report related code chunks in single place. I am also asking references so i can get help. I am gonna up vote every useful code shared. If one developer knows some part of this whole req. He can share right!

Comment: @Sivaramakrishnan you should probably read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask :) Your report requirement will most probably be different from someone else's requirement. So ideally your question has to be separated into 3 questions.

Comment: @ycr, the question and my [2-yr old response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64509896/598141) seem very similar to yours. Suggest pointing to mine (or consider upvoting mine ), unless you want elaborate on the git aspect.

Comment: @IanW I really didn't see your answer :) Anyway upvoted. Since you asked, added the full Pipeline to include commit details as well :)

Comment: @Sivaramakrishnan check the updated answer, it should have all the pieces you need :)